# Subtract cell in one column from the one prior in xlsx file in Python

Tags: python, excel, datetime

I have an xlsx file with multiple sheets. In the sheets there is column A
with time stamps (as strings). I need to subtract the cells from the one above it to see how much time has elapsed.

ex. COLUMN A

```
02/23/2017 08:25:39
02/23/2017 08:55:56
02/23/2017 08:55:57
02/23/2017 08:56:12
```

Here is what I have so far.....Thank you in advance.

```
import xlrd
from datetime import datetime

def open_file(path):

    # Open and read an Excel file

    book = xlrd.open_workbook(path)

    # get the first worksheet

    first_sheet = book.sheet_by_index(0)

    # read first column

    column_values = first_sheet.col_values(0,0)
    column_list = []

    for i in column_values:

        i = datetime.strptime(i, '%m/%d/%Y %H:%M:%S')

        column_list.append(i)

    print(column_list[1] - column_list[0])

if __name__ == "__main__":
    path = '02-23-2017.xlsx'
    open_file(path)
```

Comment: my print statement at the bottom works but there are thousands of timestamps i have to go through so i need a way to go through them programmatically .... Thank you

Answer (score 0):

You may want to check out pandas.  It handles calculations like this quickly.

```
import pandas as pd

# create a dictionary of data frames, one for each sheet
df_dict = pd.read_excel('C:/path/to/file.xlsx', sheets=None, header=None)

# iterate over each data frame
for df_key in df_dict:
    # pull the time data from the first columns
    t = pd.to_datetime(df_dict[df_key].iloc[:,0])
    # calculate the time difference using .diff(1), fillna makes the first cell 0
    dt = t.diff(1).fillna(0)
    # assign the difference to a new columns in the data frame
    df_dict[df_key]['time_delta'] = dt

# create a writer to make a new excel file
writer = pd.ExcelWriter('C:/path/to/new_file.xlsx')
# write each sheet to file
for name, df in df_dict.items():
    df.to_excel(writer, 'sheet{}'.format(name))
writer.save()
```

Answer (score 0):

Based on your existing code, you could do the following:

```
import xlrd
from datetime import datetime

def open_file(path):

    # Open and read an Excel file
    book = xlrd.open_workbook(path)

    # Open each sheet
    for sheet in book.sheet_names():
        current_sheet = book.sheet_by_name(sheet)

        # Read first column and convert to datetime objects
        column_values = [datetime.strptime(i, '%m/%d/%Y %H:%M:%S') for i in current_sheet.col_values(0, 0)]

        # Create a list of timedelta differences 
        cur = column_values[0]
        differences = []

        for i in column_values[1:]:
            differences.append(i - cur)
            cur = i

        print(sheet)

        for d in differences:  
            print("  {}".format(d))

if __name__ == "__main__":
    path = '02-23-2017.xlsx'
    open_file(path)
```

Assuming each of the sheets has the same format, this would give you something like:

```
Sheet1
  0:30:17
  0:00:01
  0:00:15
Sheet2
  0:30:17
  0:00:01
  0:00:15
Sheet3
  0:30:17
  0:00:01
  0:00:15
```